# Property scrollbar-width doesn't exist : none error

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I want to hide the scrollbar in Firefox Browser so i used the following in css:
`scrollbar-width: none;`
when i validate the css file in W3C css validator it shows me the following error:

> Property scrollbar-width doesn't exist : none

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width the Browser support isn't quit there yet.

The validator probably doesn't recognize it for this reason.

**EDIT:**
To learn how to hide the scrollbar for different browsers see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp)

Comment: so there is no way to hide the scrollbar in Firefox without getting the validation error?

Comment: I updated my answer. I initially just answered why the validator seems to fail. If the validator fails for `scrollbar-width`, but the code works, i suppose you can ignore the validator

Comment: thank you, unfortunately for my assignment it must pass the css validation

Comment: See the article of w3schools. I'd show that to my lector in that case